# What is the purpose of using the Private keyword in VB6 to declare a variable?

Tags: syntax, vb6

I have encountered this declaration inside a class. I am used to program in c# and new to vb6. Can someone tell me what is the purpose of this. Usually I see variable in vb6 are declared using Dim.

```
Private MapStatus(CAS_LAST, MAX_CAS_SLOT) As MAP_STATUS
```

where MAP_STATUS is an enum variable declared globally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with the [scope of the variable](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-variable-scope).

`private` is used outside of methods at the top of a module and makes the variable available to any methods in the module. `Dim` is used within methods and are method specific variables.

So in your case, presumably it was made private because the programmer wanted the variable available for the whole module, but not accessible from outside the module.

Comment: thanks @daniel .. Is the Mapstatus variable an array? I am confused with the paranthesis in the declaration.

Comment: @shivoham yes, it is a 2d array with fixed bounds. CAS_LAST, MAX_CAS_SLOT. VB6 arrays are 1-based by default BTW

Comment: @MarkJ: They default to 0 based.

Comment: @Deanna Thanks for the catch! Can't believe I typed that. Maybe we should mention [`Option Base`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx) to shivoham

Comment: We all slip up occasionally :p